# iTunes song iPhone 4S

Tags: itunes, iphone

If I delete a song I got in iTunes from my iPhone 4S (IOS 6.3) do I have to pay again to download it? I have never sync with a PC or MAC, so it exists only in my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

In the iTunes app on the phone, there is a "Purchased" tab. In there, you should be able to see everything that you have previously purchased, and download them anew.